# “What a relief?” – Why do we need an article?

Tags: articles, usage

“Oxford learners Dictionary” states that “relief” (at least when it means removal of anxiety/pain) is an uncountable noun. Then why do we use the indefinite article in this phrase? Are there any other phrases where “relief” requires an article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Relief" can mean the end of pain or discomfort (uncountable), or the thing that brought about that end (countable).  It's used both ways.

Answer (score 3):

The full Oxford Dictionaries entry includes the countable-noun meaning of 'relief':

> Relief (noun)
>
> 1.1 count noun
>   A cause of or occasion for relief.
>   ‘it was a relief to find somewhere to stay’

[Relief (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/relief)

Its use with an article is shown, but not explained, in the Oxford Learner's Dictionary:

> News of their safety came as a great relief.
>   It was a relief to be able to talk to someone about it.
>   What a relief!